# weird icons in google apps script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I have noticed that some of the icons in the "toolbar" are not displaying correctly in my GAS editor. Here is an image of what I am seeing:
[image]

However, when I decrease the scaling in my browser (Google Chrome), I see the right icons:

[image]

The problem is that with this scaling the font size is too small. I was suspecting it might have something to do with my high DPI monitor.

Anyone know how to fix this behavior? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also get this when I open the editor in mobile...it's a bug you can report it

Comment: You might to add the **google-apps-script-editor** tag to your question.

Comment: I see this at *normal size* zoom (100%) on my high DPI (3840x2160) display. I have to change the zoom to 67% before the icons appear normally.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you zoom in a lot.  It happens to me around a zoom of 175.  It's been that way for a long time as far as I know.